# PHP check with foreach if array exist inside a txt file and return boolean

Tags: php, boolean

I know it is basic code but somewhere is a mistake that I can not figure out after hours. Inside the blocklist.txt are several lines of IP's which should check if is existing or give boolean true or false out. I do not get the boolean true out even if it matches.

```
function blocklist($ip) {
    $blocked = false;
    $ipList = file('blocklist.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) // ip in array
        or exit("Unable to open blocklist file");

    foreach ($ipList as $entry) {
        if(strpos($entry, $ip)) { // check if ip exist in array
            $blocked = true; // set true
            break; 
        }
        echo $blocked ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
    return $blocked;
}

function getUserIP() {
    $ip = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else
        $ip = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ip;
}
```

blocklist.txt content

```
123.45.67.89
464.93.47.37
95.83.46.359
237.8.54.849
```

Comment: please share sample for `blocklist.txt`

Comment: try `strpos($entry, $ip) !== false` because its going to be returning `0`

Comment: Result again 0 (false). I have tried also `strstr($entry, $ip, true)` and still getting result as 0

Comment: I tested your function changing to `strpos($entry, $ip) !== false` and  `blocklist('464.93.47.37')` returns `true`, note that `blocklist('464.93')` would also return true, so better do a whole line comparison (maybe with a `trim($entry)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse IP from `blocklist.txt` in `$ipList` variable then extra space is added to every IP,so I removed the whitespace from every value in `$ipList` using

`array_map('trim',$ipList)`

```
function blocklist($ip) {
    //remove white space from input array
    $ip = trim($ip);
    $blocked = false;
    $ipList = file('blocklist.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) // ip in array
        or exit("Unable to open blocklist file");
    //remove the white space from each value 
    $ipList = array_map('trim',$ipList);
    //Check if IP exist in the array list 
    if(in_array($ip,$ipList)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function getUserIP() {
    $ip = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else
        $ip = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ip;
}

var_dump(blocklist('123.45.67.89')); //output true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to break your file contents into an array, make iterated `trim()` calls to remove the whitespace from each element, then scan the new prepared array for an identical value match.

Is there a good reason not to do this?  A single function call will be much more efficient/direct.

```
function blocklist($ip){
    if(!$ipList=file_get_contents('blocklist.txt')){
        exit("Unable to open blocklist file");
    }
    return preg_match('/\b\Q'.$ip.'\E\b/',$ipList) ? true : false;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/028b7752326b4988ceff2ab1b9f1e3165fa629f0) with a static `$ipList` string:

```
function blocklist($ip){
    $ipList='123.45.67.89
464.93.47.12
464.93.47.123
95.83.46.359
237.8.54.849';
    //                  vv-----------vv-Word Boundaries to ensure no extra digits are matched
    return preg_match('/\b\Q'.$ip.'\E\b/',$ipList) ? true : false;
    //                    ^^-------^^-Interpret $ip string literally, so dots are not "any character" (only important in extreme fringe cases)
}

var_export(blocklist('464.93.47.123'));  // true
var_export(blocklist('464.93.1.123'));  // false
```

---

Otherwise if you have your heart set on processing an array, perform a single loop with an early exit possibility (not a `array_map()` then an `in_array()`:

```
function blocklist($ip){
    $ipList = file('blocklist.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) // ip in array
              or exit("Unable to open blocklist file");
    foreach ($ipList as $entry) {
        if($ip===trim($entry)) { // check if ip value is element value
            return true; // set true and early exit
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Also, the other function can be refined to use a simpler / shorter syntax:

```
function getUserIP() {
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    return 'UNKNOWN';
}
```

Comment: @karadayi I was late to arrive at this question, but please have a look at my refined/optimized methods for your task.  My two `blocklist()` functions will improve your code's performance.